# Firestore took too long to fetch data therefore I couldn't display it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function which fetch a data from Firestore :

```
  getLastTime(collectionName: string) {
    const docRef = this.afs.firestore.collection(collectionName).doc(this.User).collection('lastTime').doc('lastTime');
    docRef.get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
          this.get = doc.data().lastTime;
      } else {
          this.get = 'Never done';
      }
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Error getting document:', error);
  });
    return this.get;
  }
```

For my test I actually have a string value inside the doc 'lastTime' which is a string.

Inside ngOnInit(), I called my function and console.log the result

```
this.InjuredLastTime = this.getLastTime('INJURY');
console.log(this. this.InjuredLastTime);
```

Normally I should have my string printed inside the console but I got undefined...

Maybe it's because Firestore do not fetch fast enough my data, but I am quiet surprised since Firestore is quiet fast normally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually wait for the promise that is created by `docRef.get()` before you return from `getLastTime()`.  So, unless the call to firebase is instant (e.g. never) this won't work.

The correct solution really depends on what you are doing with `this.InjuredLastTime`.  But one approach would just be to return a promise and set it after it is ready:

```js
getLastTime(collectionName: string) {
    const docRef = this.afs.firestore.collection(collectionName).doc(this.User).collection('lastTime').doc('lastTime');
    return docRef.get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
          return doc.data().lastTime;
      } else {
          return 'Never done';
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Error getting document:', error);
      return null;
    });
}
```

Then, instead of the assignment synchronously, do it asynchronously:

```js
this.getLastTime('INJURY').then(result => { this.InjuredLastTime = result });
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, since it may take some time before the data comes back from the server. To prevent having to block the browser, your code is instead allowed to continue to run, and then your callback is called when the data is available.

You can easily see this with a few well-placed log statements:

```
const docRef = this.afs.firestore.collection(collectionName).doc(this.User).collection('lastTime').doc('lastTime');
console.log('Before starting to get data');
docRef.get().then(doc => {
  console.log('Got data');
});
console.log('After starting to get data');
```

If you run this code, you'll get:

> Before starting to get data
>
> After starting to get data
>
> Got data

This is probably not the order that you expected the logging output in, but it is actually the correct behavior. And it completely explains why you're getting `undefined` out of your `getLastTime`  function: by the time `return this.get;` runs, the data hasn't loaded yet.

The simplest solution in modern JavaScript is to mark your function as `async` and then `await` its result. That would look something like this:

```
async function getLastTime(collectionName: string) {
    const docRef = this.afs.firestore.collection(collectionName).doc(this.User).collection('lastTime').doc('lastTime');
    doc = await docRef.get();
    if (doc.exists) {
        this.get = doc.data().lastTime;
    } else {
        this.get = 'Never done';
    }
    return this.get;
}
```

And then call it with:

```
this.InjuredLastTime = await this.getLastTime('INJURY');
```